# How to find child window loaded completely in Java Script

Tags: javascript

In my parent window I am using window.open and passing external url to render, I wanted to know whether child window is loaded completely.I will not have any control on child window content. I am looking for solution something like if http status of child window is 200 then kind of child window is loaded.

Parent Window.

```
var childWindow = window.open("externalUrl", 200px, 300px);
```

Comment: How about `childWindow.onload=function(){//callback};`

Comment: That "externalUrl" parameter is going to be an issue; you won't have access to pages outside the same origin policy.

Comment: @RayonDabre Tried `childWindow.onload=function(){//callback};` ?

Comment: @guest271314, Thats was a guess..Let me know it that is _invalid_!

Comment: @RayonDabre `function(){//callback};` would be printed to `console` , not called ; `onload` property may not exist at opened `window`, or be accessible by opener . Could try using an IIFE `childWindow.onload = (function() {console.log(123)}())` , though this would not indicate actual `onload` event of opened `window` ?

Comment: @guest271314, _w is not defined_

Comment: @RayonDabre http://plnkr.co/edit/IugupG1bZUEkpjzRew5h

Comment: @guest271314, You are right !